# Using Poco with QtCreator (Windows)

Tags: qt-creator, poco-libraries

I'm trying to use Poco 1.6.0 in QtCreator, and I'm getting some strange errors on my build. Most of the errors are along the following theme:

```
    warning: 'void Poco::Dynamic::Var::swap(Poco::Dynamic::Var&)' redeclared without dllimport attribute after being referenced with dll linkage
```

I've built Poco with MinGW and was planning to use that, but to no avail. I've also built Poco with VS2012, but get similar errors.

Thoughts? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this issue had more to do with the kit being used in QtCreator. The MinGW kit doesn't seem to link properly with non-MinGW created DLLs. There was some level of name-mangling and/or dllexport mismanagement when dealing with Poco DLLs from Qt/MinGW. I don't remember all the specific errors. Additionally, MinGW isn't an "officially supported port of Poco". So that didn't help; however, the onus was really on the MinGW kit in QtCreator.

That all being said, Poco compiled with MSVC2013 worked well with the same code as referenced above, but compiled with the MSVC kit in QtCreator. Likewise, Poco built on Unbuntu worked well with my QtCreator install there. So it isn't that Poco didn't work with QtCreator - it is that MinGW didn't/doesn't work with Poco.

I hope someone else finds this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with QtCreator but the way DLLs work is that the classes and functions made available ("exported") for applications when DLL is built are declared as *export*, but those same functions and classes then must be declared as *import* from the application side. See [Foundation.h](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/develop/Foundation/include/Poco/Foundation.h#L42-L55) to understand how this happens and which defines you need on the application side (you could be missing _WIN32 and/or _DLL so [POCO_DLL](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/develop/Foundation/include/Poco/Foundation.h#L36) may not be defined). Typically, this happens automatically during build - Foundation_API will be defined as *export* when a Poco library is built and *import* when your application is built.